# SignalR Library: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, signalr, dex

I am trying to work with the [SignarR client library](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client)  created by folks at Microsoft.  But when I try to run the [signalr-clent-test-integration-android] and load it in either simulator or the device I get the following error.  based on the research I have found out that there is overlapping dependency and for some reason Java doesn't like it.  The dependency here is for the [signalr-client-skd] library used by [signalr-client-sdk-android] and [signalr-client-test-integration-base] libraries which is used by [signalr-clent-test-integration-android] android app.

So, could some one guide on how to solve this issue please?  Not sure whether folks at Microsoft even tested this test app at all. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Executing tasks: [:signalr-client-test-integration-android:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:preBuild
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:compileDebugNdk
:signalr-client-sdk:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk:classes UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk:jar UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:compileLint
:signalr-client-sdk-android:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:preBuild
:signalr-client-sdk-android:preReleaseBuild
:signalr-client-sdk-android:checkReleaseManifest
:signalr-client-sdk-android:preDebugBuild
:signalr-client-sdk-android:preDebugTestBuild
:signalr-client-sdk-android:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:prepareReleaseDependencies
:signalr-client-sdk-android:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-sdk-android:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:preDebugBuild
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:checkDebugManifest
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:preReleaseBuild
:signalr-client-test-integration-base:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-base:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-base:classes UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-base:jar UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:prepareSignalRSignalrClientSdkAndroidUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:prepareDebugDependencies
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:signalr-client-test-integration-android:compileDebugJava
Note: C:\IM1\Device Projects\Android\SignalR\SignalR\signalr-client-test-integration-android\src\main\java\microsoft\aspnet\signalr\client\test\integration\android\MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:signalr-client-test-integration-android:preDexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing microsoft/aspnet/signalr/client/test/integration/ApplicationContext$1.class

1 error; aborting

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing microsoft/aspnet/signalr/client/Action.class

1 error; aborting

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':signalr-client-test-integration-android:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\adt-bundle\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --output C:\IM1\Device Projects\Android\SignalR\SignalR\signalr-client-test-integration-android\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\signalr-client-sdk-22e3214ec8048293555e1dae6b0ea2a34310b794.jar C:\IM1\Device Projects\Android\SignalR\SignalR\signalr-client-sdk\build\libs\signalr-client-sdk.jar
Error Code:
    1
Output:

    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    ...while parsing microsoft/aspnet/signalr/client/Action.class

    1 error; aborting


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.289 secs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of google searches and banging my head against the wall, we finally figured it out.  It is definitely something to do with Java 8.  Therefore you cannot use Java 8 in Android for now if you have libraries referencing each other.

The solution for this problem is not just telling the Android to use compiler to 1.7 or earlier but **having the 1.7 JDK installed physically** on your computer and setting the JDK location to point to it.  This can be found under [**Project  Structure**] -> [**SDK Location**] -> [**JDK Location**].  Phew!!!

Thanks to my colleague who had 1.7 and 1.6 installed parallel on his machine and he switched the JDK Location to 1.7 and it just worked!  So, I had to download the 1.7.x JDK and installed it on my computer in order to work!  This is ridiculous but works! :)

If this is the case what the heck that Compiler setting is there for under **Build, Execution, Deployment** in **Default Settings**?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant error is `bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)`. Version 0x34 is for java 8 classes, which android does not currently support.

Your best bet is to try rebuild the client jar with java 1.7 compatibility.